# nginx two sites one directory

Tags: php, nginx

I have a project where I want to have one domain per language. So my sites are pointing at the same directory, but for some reason, one of my domains are being redirected to the other.

To clarify.
example.com
example.org

example.org is pointed to the same directory as example.com.

When I visit example.org, I get redirected to example.com

I don't know if the problem is that I use LetsEncrypt SSL on both domains.

Any clues?

Here is my nginx files

example.com

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/example.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/forge/example.com;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/xxx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/xxx/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'XXXXXX-$'
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/example.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ~ /(public/mail-signature/.*)$ {

    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/example.com/after/*;
```

example.org

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/example.org/before/*;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.org;
    root /home/forge/example.com;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'xxxxxxx-$'
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/example.org/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.org-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/example.org/after/*;
```

Comment: nothing here that would redirect you. either its some include file that you're not showing (you do include `/*` several places), or it's php redirecting. what does `curl -v --location example.org 2>&1 | pastebinit`  say?

Comment: First vhost only listens on 443, and the second only on 80 ...

Comment: Run `nginx -T` and paste the generated config in your question or a pastebin.com link

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a more agnostic name for your document root, otherwise is very easy to get confused, you could use something like:

```
/home/forge/site-example
```

Later try to use [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html) to diagnose your flow, for example:

```
curl -I -L https://google.com
```

The option `-I` will fetch only headers

And option `-L` will follow redirects

For example for the site http://immortal.run

```
$ curl -I -L http://immortal.run
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 15 Sep 2017 14:58:43 GMT
...

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 15 Sep 2017 14:58:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
...
```

Notice the:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

That is something probably is happening with your setup.

Comment: curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name (example.com) does not match target host name 'example.com'

Comment: You have to use a certificate per domain